# Upload multiple pdf files through API Gateway Lambda AWS- Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, api-gateway

I am having an issue passing the file name while uploading it to S3 using API Gateway-Lambda. How should I pass files name dynamically, meaning users should put multiple files and original file names should be there upon landing to S3.Here is my code,

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):

  try:
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")
    buffer = BytesIO()
    get_file_content = event["body"]
    content = base64.b64decode(get_file_content)
    s3_upload = s3.put_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key= "test.pdf", Body = content )

    return {
     "statuscode" : 200,
     "body" : json.dumps("complete")
   }
  except Exception as e:
          logger.error(
                "Error uploading files"
                ": {}".format(e)
                )
          raise e
```

Comment: Where are you using `buffer` and `context` variables in the code? Why are you not entering the object name as a parameter in the function call and use it in `put_object`?

Comment: are you trying upload multiple files through single request

Comment: yes, multiple files through single request.

Comment: @cloudroy, how did you achieve this